# Connection to SQS queue refused after AWS java SDK upgrade

Tags: java, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk

Here is my connection code:

```
SqsClient client = SqsClient.builder()
    .region(Region.EU_WEST_1)
    .credentialsProvider(
        StaticCredentialsProvider.create(
            AwsBasicCredentials.create("myAccessKeyId", "myAccessKeySecret")
        )
    )
    .endpointOverride(URI.create("https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/..."))
    .build();
ReceiveMessageRequest rmr = ReceiveMessageRequest.builder()
    .maxNumberOfMessages(1)
    .build();
ReceiveMessageResponse receiveMessageResponse = client.receiveMessage(rmr);
// ...
```

It works well with SDK `software.amazon.awssdk:sqs` until last preview version (`2.0.0-preview-13`).

From version `2.1.0` and above (`2.1.x`, `2.2.x`, `2.3.x`), same code (and same parameters) compiles but fails at runtime with this error:

`software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.model.QueueDoesNotExistException: The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version. (Service: Sqs, Status Code: 400, Request ID: ...)`

Back to `2.0.0-preview-*`, it works.

What am I missing to upgrade SDK version?
Is an action required on the queue itself (we don't have access to Amazon administration: the queue is provided)?